# Retrofit 2 Calls onFailure Method after Posting Parameters to API

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an app that posts several variables to an API and returns responses from the API via `Retrofit2`. This is actually a payment model where the user's `paymentAmount` , `paymentType` ,`userID` ,`billNumber` is sent to the API for payment process and responses are received in an `AlertDialog` to tell whether payment process was successful or not.

The issue here is that the API successfully receives my variables to initialize a payment process however it doesn't return the `onResponse` method. Rather the `onFailure` method is called making it unable to receive responses from the API.

This is the log i recieve when i call Throwable `t.getCause()` from the `onFailure` method. Please Help.

```
04-23 20:20:32.368 25592-25592/com.example.gamor.rhema E/ContentValues: Unable to submit post to API.java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

**API Response Format**

```
{
  "RespCode": "0",
  "PaymentNumber": "PYMNT000000000375",
  "PaymentAmount": 0.5,
  "PaymentDate": "4/23/2018 6:55:09 PM",
  "Respmessage": "Successful"
}
```

**My API Interface - APIServicePayBill.java**

```
public interface APIServicePayBill {

 @POST("PayBills")
 @FormUrlEncoded
 Call<PostPayBill> savePostPayBill(@Field("AccountNumber") String AccountNumber,
                                  @Field("Amount") float Amount,
                                  @Field("Paytype") String Paytype,
                                  @Field("BillNumber") String BillNumber);
}
```

**JSON POJO Class - PostPayBill.java**

```
public class PostPayBill {

@SerializedName("RespCode")
@Expose
private String respCode;
@SerializedName("PaymentNumber")
@Expose
private String paymentNumber;
@SerializedName("PaymentAmount")
@Expose
private float paymentAmount;
@SerializedName("PaymentDate")
@Expose
private String paymentDate;
@SerializedName("Respmessage")
@Expose
private String respmessage;

public String getRespCode() {
    return respCode;
}

public void setRespCode(String respCode) {
    this.respCode = respCode;
}

public String getPaymentNumber() {
    return paymentNumber;
}

public void setPaymentNumber(String paymentNumber) {
    this.paymentNumber = paymentNumber;
}

public float getPaymentAmount() {
    return paymentAmount;
}

public void setPaymentAmount(float paymentAmount) {
    this.paymentAmount = paymentAmount;
}

public String getPaymentDate() {
    return paymentDate;
}

public void setPaymentDate(String paymentDate) {
    this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
}

public String getRespmessage() {
    return respmessage;
}

public void setRespmessage(String respmessage) {
    this.respmessage = respmessage;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PostPayBill{" +
            "respCode='" + respCode + '\'' +
            ", paymentNumber='" + paymentNumber + '\'' +
            ", paymentAmount=" + paymentAmount +
            ", paymentDate='" + paymentDate + '\'' +
            ", respmessage='" + respmessage + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

**ApiUtils Class - ApiUtils.java**

```
public class ApiUtils {

private ApiUtils() {}

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.1.123.11/api/";

public static APIServicePayBill getUserServicePayBill(){
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIServicePayBill.class);
}

}
```

**API Initialising**

```
apiServicePayBill = ApiUtils.getUserServicePayBill();
```

**Payment Method**

```
private void sentPayBillsDetails(String AccountNumber, float Amount, String Paytype, String BillNumber ) {
    apiServicePayBill.savePostPayBill(AccountNumber,Amount,Paytype,BillNumber).enqueue(new Callback<PostPayBill>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostPayBill> call, Response<PostPayBill> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());

                if ( progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder registrationAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MakePaymentActivity.this);
                registrationAlert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#125688'>PAYMENT STATUS</font>"));
                registrationAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_box);
                registrationAlert.setMessage("Payment Number: "+response.body().getPaymentNumber()+
                                            "\nPayment Amount: "+response.body().getPaymentAmount()+
                                            "\nPayment Date: "+response.body().getPaymentDate()+
                                            "\nMessage: "+response.body().getRespmessage());
                registrationAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        gotoRegistrationPage();
                    }
                });

                registrationAlert.setCancelable(false);

                AlertDialog alertDialog = registrationAlert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostPayBill> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API."+t.getCause());

            if ( progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder registrationAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MakePaymentActivity.this);
            registrationAlert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#125688'>PAYMENT STATUS</font>"));
            registrationAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_box);
            registrationAlert.setMessage("Unable to submit post to API");
            registrationAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    gotoFaliedPage();
                }
            });

            registrationAlert.setCancelable(false);

            AlertDialog alertDialog = registrationAlert.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
}
```

**Gradle File**

```
  // Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

// JSON Parsing
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Did you write the API too?  It looks like the server is closing the socket before your client reads the response.

Comment: The API was written by an external person. But it runs fine when I try the API with postman.